# Cannot Fire intent by casting string to class

Tags: android, class, android-intent

I have created a Listview form which i want to fire intents for specific classes.Here **var:position** is the position of the ListView row which i have Clicked.I am getting ClassNotFoundException irrespective of all the activity in the same package & correct names.

```
String[] slideMenuOptions = {"CarGallery.class","connectus.class","BookService.class"};
String str = slideMenuOptions[position];
Class <?> c = Class.forName(str);
Intent intent = new Intent(context,c);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Remove `.class` from the strings.   The String value is interpreted as a literal representation of the class name.

Comment: Still the Same problem java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: `new Intent(context,c.class);` ?

Comment: From a project I just happen to be working on right now.  This code has been working for months.  thisClass = Class.forName(context.getPackageName() + "." + thisDict.getClassName();) which reminded me that Class.forName requires the fully qualified package name.

Answer (score 0):

use full name of class without .class to get class name and start next Activity as :

```
String[] slideMenuOptions = {"xx.xxx.CarGallery",
                             "xx.xxx.connectus",
                             "xx.xxx.BookService"};
String str = slideMenuOptions[position];
Class <?> c = Class.forName(str);
Intent intent = new Intent(context,c);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

ad make sure you have declared all activity in `androidmanifest.xml` file

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to give full qualified class name. 
For example if your CarGallery.class has the package 
then you should give your CarGaller class along with package name.
com.tech.CarGaller.
I used the following code. Its working great to me. If you have any issues, please let me know.
```

```
/*String[] slideMenuOptions = {"com.tech.CarGallery","com.tech.connectus","com.tech.BookService"};*/
String[] slideMenuOptions = {"xx.xxx.CarGallery","xx.xxx.connectus","xx.xxx.BookService"};
String str = slideMenuOptions[1];
Class  c = Class.forName(str);
System.out.println("get class name"+c.getName());
Intent intent = new Intent(context,c);
context.startActivity(intent);
```